# javascript dollar sign variable not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, wordpress, dom

I have following code in my Wordpress:

```
(function ($) {
  var $header = $("div.header");

  $(window).bind("scroll resize", function () {
    if ($(window).scrollTop() > 30) {
      $("div.header").stop().animate({
        'opacity': 0.24
      }, {
        duration: 1000
      });
    } else {
      $header.stop().animate({
        'opacity': 1
      }, {
        duration: 1000
      });
    }
  });
})(jQuery);
```

If statement kicks in when supposed but else never...

BUT

If I enclose it with:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {        
  // code here
});
```

It's all fine. Why?

Thank you

Comment: What is the javascript error occuring or provide your wordpress url containing error so we can answer correctly.

Comment: "Why doesn't it work??" is not an error message that I'm familiar with.

Comment: @ExplosionPills: it's like "the sky is blue" and "water is wet" and "gravity is a downer" and "friction is a drag". true, but useless.

Comment: I've just edited my code. Hope it is all demystified now. I am not getting any JS errors reported in Chrome.

Comment: What's the error ? Is `$header` being declared ? What's `$header` value ?

Comment: There is no error, it is very silent. It alerts object so it is declared.

Comment: I don't know if it makes any difference but jquery library is loaded by Wordpress latest version(3.4.1)

Comment: -1 **Just because "this code" and the "original code" are too drastically different.** Please take time to write good question not filled with bogus information.

Comment: @pst don't you dare... look now there is even more

Comment: As others have pointed out, in one case (`$header = ..`), the DOM is being accessed (though the jQuery element selector) *before* it is ready .. there are plenty of duplicates on this. The event fires sometime *after* the DOM is ready.

Comment: @SperanskyDanil I have just now... it's fine now. I thought that it represents `document.ready` already... Was I wrong?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

May be you're trying to use jQuery when dom in not build. Try to use `$(document).ready` function:

```
(function ($) {
  $(document).ready(function () {
    $header = $("div.header");
    $header.remove();
  });
})(jQuery);
```

About what you have mantioned in the question:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
  // code
});
```

It works because it do the same thing: it binds event handler on `ready` event and pass `jQuery` object as a parameter to the function as `$`.

Now what you did before:

```
(function ($) {
  $header = $("div.header");
  $header.remove();
})(jQuery);
```

Here you just declare anonymous function with named `$` parameter:

```
function ($) {
}
```

And call it with `jQuery` object as a parameter, which will be available in the function as `$`:

```
(function ($) {
})(jQuery);
```